# How to draw a rectangle with a straight line as the central axis?

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, drawing

[image: rectangle]

As shown in the image above, the red line as the central axis to draw the black rectangle. Given the starting point corrdinate and end point coordinate of the red line and the width of the rectangle, how to draw the rectangle?

I am writing an extension method of `System.Drawing.Graphics` to implement it. The starting point position and end point position of the straight line, and the width of the rectangle are passed as parameters to the method. But how to write drawing rectangle logic next?

```
public static void DrawRectangleWithLine(this Graphics g, Pen pen, Vector3 startPointPosition, Vector3 endPointPosition, int width)
{
    double length = Math.Pow(Math.Pow(startPointPosition.X - endPointPosition.X, 2) + Math.Pow(startPointPosition.Y - endPointPosition.Y, 2), 0.5);
    double slope = (startPointPosition.Y - endPointPosition.Y) / (startPointPosition.X - endPointPosition.X);
    double angle = Math.Atan(slope);
    // draw the four sides of the rectangle
    g.DrawLine()
    g.DrawLine()
    g.DrawLine()
    g.DrawLine()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

1. Calculate the length of the rectangle from the starting point position and ending point position.
2. Calculate the slope of the line from the starting point position and ending point position.
3. Calculate the angle from the slope.
4. Calculate the four vertices Position of the rectangle.
5. Connect the four vertices of the rectangle with stright lines.

```
public static void DrawRectangleWithLine(this Graphics g, Pen pen, Vector3 startPointPosition, Vector3 endPointPosition, int width)
{
    double length = Math.Pow(Math.Pow(startPointPosition.X - endPointPosition.X, 2) + Math.Pow(startPointPosition.Y - endPointPosition.Y, 2), 0.5);
    double slope = (startPointPosition.Y - endPointPosition.Y) / (startPointPosition.X - endPointPosition.X);
    double angle = Math.Atan(slope);
    Vector3 p1 = new Vector3(startPointPosition.X - width / 2 * Math.Sin(angle), startPointPosition.Y + width / 2 * Math.Cos(angle));
    Vector3 p2 = new Vector3(startPointPosition.X + width / 2 * Math.Sin(angle), startPointPosition.Y - width / 2 * Math.Cos(angle));
    Vector3 p3 = new Vector3(p1.X + length * Math.Cos(angle), p1.Y + length * Math.Sin(angle));
    Vector4 p4 = new Vector3(p2.X + length * Math.Cos(angle), p2.Y + length * Math.Sin(angle));
    g.DrawLine(pen, p1.ToPointF(), p2.ToPointF());
    g.DrawLine(pen, p2.ToPointF(), p4.ToPointF());
    g.DrawLine(pen, p4.ToPointF(), p3.ToPointF());
    g.DrawLine(pen, p3.ToPointF(), p1.ToPointF());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative approach that doesn't require you to calculate the actual coords of the rotated rectangle.

Instead, we translate and rotate the entire graphics surface and draw a correctly sized "normal" rectangle:

```
public static void DrawRectangleWithLine(this Graphics g, Pen pen, Vector3 startPointPosition, Vector3 endPointPosition, int width)
{            
    // Draw the Red Line with the Original Coordinates
    g.ResetTransform();
    g.DrawLine(Pens.Red, startPointPosition, endPointPosition);

    // Draw the Rectangle around the Red Line
    // by moving the origin and rotating the surface
    double length = Math.Pow(Math.Pow(startPointPosition.X - endPointPosition.X, 2) + Math.Pow(startPointPosition.Y - endPointPosition.Y, 2), 0.5);
    Point midPoint = new Point(
        (startPointPosition.X + endPointPosition.X) / 2,
        (startPointPosition.Y + endPointPosition.Y)/2);
    float deltaX = endPointPosition.X - startPointPosition.X;
    float deltaY = endPointPosition.Y - startPointPosition.Y;
    float angle = (float)(Math.Atan2(deltaY, deltaX) * 180.0 / Math.PI);
    g.TranslateTransform(midPoint.X, midPoint.Y);
    g.RotateTransform((float)angle);

    // Method 1 of making the Rectangle:
    Rectangle rc = new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), new Size(0, 0));
    rc.Inflate((int)(length / 2), width / 2);            
    g.DrawRectangle(pen, rc);

    // Method 2 of making the Rectangle:
    Rectangle rc2 = new Rectangle(new Point(-(int)(length / 2), -width / 2), new Size((int)length, width));
    g.DrawRectangle(pen, rc2);
}
```

An example of it being used in WinForms:

- I used `Point` instead of `Vector3` below!
- Rectangle shown is via Method 1

Code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private Point startPoint = new Point(150, 500);
    private Point endPoint = new Point(650, 200);

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangleWithLine(Pens.Black, startPoint, endPoint, 50);
    }

}
```

Output:

[image]